# Determining the limit of a multivariable function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have the limit below:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{sin(x^4y)}{x^4 + x^2y^2}$$

I have tried to solve it with polar coordinates and get:

x = r cos t
y = r sin t

$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{sin(r^4⋅cos^4t⋅r⋅sint)}{r^4⋅cos^4t + r^2⋅cos^2t⋅r^2⋅sin^2t}$$

$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{sin(r^5⋅cos^4t⋅sint)}{r^4 (cos^4t + cos^2t⋅sin^2t)}$$

since r approaches 0, I will get a 0 in the numerator and the denominator:
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{0}{0} = undefined$$

I get that the limit is undefined, but it should be 0 according to WolframAlpha, can anyone help me out, please. Perhaps polar coordinates is not the right approach here?

Comment: Is this something you could please help me with?:) @AndréArmatowski

Comment: In $\lim_{(x,y) \to (6,1)} \frac{sin(5x + y)}{7 + y^8}$ you can just insert values, but, may be for each new exercise is more better to open new question with showing own efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}0&\leqslant\left|\frac{\sin(x^4y)}{x^4+x^2y^2}\right|\\&=\frac{|\sin(x^4y)|}{x^4+x^2y^2}\\&\leqslant\frac{x^4|y|}{x^4+x^2y^2}\\&=\frac{x^2|y|}{x^2+y^2}\\&\leqslant|y|.\end{align}So, since $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}|y|=0$, it follows from the squeeze theorem that your limit is $0$ too.

Comment: This is different from the  limit OP wants.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Take a look at the [original version](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3791642/revisions) of the question.

Comment: Very sorry. I am upvoting your answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you.